# which one to choose react-native-router-flux or react-router-native or react-navigation

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner to react-native and am trying to achieve redirecting, and routing to another page after authenticating the login ..etc

which one should I choose react-native-router-flux or react-router-native or react-navigation
or how can achieve my things are routing , redirecting etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with react-navigation. 
It's simple.
[ i have tried wix's react-native-navigation the problem with rnn is it's setup is hectic ]

For more comparison visit link below.

https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/choosing-a-routing-library-for-react-native-604f97e58729

Comment: what you meant react applications , is it react web apps.?

Comment: @Ramusesan Right

Answer (score 7):

It really comes down to what your preference is.

1) react-native-router-flux is just the wrapper around react-navigation but is a 
   lot easier to work with but it does not have a very good documentation and 
   some times you will have to look into react-navigation documentation for how 
   certain things work.

2) wix/react-native-navigation is native side solution for navigation a bit 
   difficult to work with but transitions are very smooth and it helps with app's 
   performance since it offloads work from javascript thread.

link: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation

3) If you are new react-native i would suggest you go with react-navigation it's 
   the most popular as of now and can cover all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

"react-native-router-flux" is good as it provide many features like drawers, lightbox, modals etc and also passing the props from one scene to another is quite simple.
Reference of features: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md
Example refrence : https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/tree/master/Example

Comment: what about  react-navigation